# How to create a upload/reference widget/field for dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm using archetypes.uploadreferencewidget in many projects because it let my customers having one folder 'images' that is shared with all content types to produce a shared content lead image.

Now I want to do that with dexterity, but I have never created z3cform widgets / or fields. I have search for this kind of widgets but I have not find it.

So how should I create this. Is a simple z3cform widget can achieve an upload and bening configurable as it is for archetypes.uploadreferencewidget ? I have the feeling this is responsability of the field but can't understand why / why not.

Any ideas are welcome.